# Deploy jar files from multi-project gradle build to destination directory

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build in which I want to deploy all the jars that are built from the multiple projects into a destination directory and just can't figure out how to do it exactly.

The directory structure is pretty standard:

```
.
├── project1
│   ├── build
│   │   └── libs
│   │       └── project1.jar
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
├── project2
│   ├── build
│   │   └── libs
│   │       └── project2.jar
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
├── build.gradle
├── gradle.properties
└── settings.gradle
```

I need to get `project1.jar` & `project2.jar` copied into a destination directory.

Another problem is that the number of projects will continue to grow.  So in a few weeks there will likely be a `project3.jar`.  It would be nice if I didn't have to update anything to get its jar files included in the copy as well (other than editing my settings.gradle file to include project3 in the build).

Just copying `./*/build/libs/*.jar` to some destination directory would work for me I think, I just don't know how to do that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add the following piece of code to `build.gradle` in `project1` and `project2`:

```
jar {
   destinationDir project.file('../dest')
}
```

**EDIT** (after discussion in comments)

You need to add the following piece of code to root build.gradle file

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
}

task copyFiles(type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
   from(subprojects.jar)
   into project.file('dest')
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for more of a way to deploy the jar files rather than just changing where they are created.

Comment: Ok. Update question that describes the scenario well.

Comment: Just updated the question @Opal, hopefully it is more clear.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. This is still the same. If You change the directory a jar file is created You'll get the result You're looking for. If I have some time this evening will try to implement it using Copy task, but i'm not sure if this is needed.

Comment: I need the jar files to not be deployed immediately when they are created.  They need to be tested first, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the jars outside of the project directory (/tmp)?

Comment: If 'into' is set to '/tmp' then I end up with a './tmp' directory as a sibling to project1 & project2, not '/tmp' like I want. It seems like copy will only move files around in the project, but not outside of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a supplement to [Opal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856408/deploy-jar-files-from-multi-project-gradle-build-to-destination-directory#24858896):

If you want to copy only a subset of your subprojects' jars you can apply a filter like this:

```
/** Returns true if a project has a source directory */
def hasSrc(proj){
    return new File(proj.projectDir, "src").exists()
}

/** Copies the jars of the subprojects to a dir of the umbrella project */
task copyJars(type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
        // Skip empty subprojects
        from(subprojects.findAll{hasSrc(it)}.jar)
        into project.file("$buildDir/jars")
}
run.dependsOn copyJars
```